# Passing a string to .loc accessor pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index, pandas-loc

I have a dataframe which is multi-index and passing a list or a string to the loc accessor doesn't work.

My dataframe has two indexes : `Name_1, Name_2`.

Let `tempList=[ 'Marco John' , Peter Dorset']`

`data.loc['Marco John','Peter Dorset']['Combined Salary']` works

`data.loc[tempList[0],tempList[1]]['Combined Salary']` works

`data.loc[tempList]['Combined Salary']` doesn't work?

```
tempstring = tempList[0]+','+templist[1]

data.loc[tempstring]['Combined Salary']
```

doesn't work?

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with passing a string to the loc accessor?

Comment: Please share sample for your dataframe. The value in .loc[row_indexer, column_indexer], you can pass any two values for row_indexer or column_indexer. It doesn't accept a string or list.

Answer (score 0):

The following code results in an indexer equal to `"Marco John,Peter Dorset"`; which is a format not acceptable by pandas

```
tempstring = tempList[0]+','+templist[1]
data.loc[tempstring]['Combined Salary']
```

Did you try the following?

```
data.loc[*tempList]['Combined Salary']
```

The `*` operator before `tempList` should unpack the list

Comment: No it doesn't work data.loc[*tempList]['Combined Salary'] returns a syntax error.  I have checked the version of python I am using and it is 3.7.4